# NativeScript Typings

Tags: mobile, typescript, nativescript

I'm working through the NativeScript getting started tutorial in TypeScript:
http://developer.telerik.com/featured/getting-started-nativescript/

In one snippet of code, I see:

```
exports.loadSignUpView = function(args) {
    page = args.object;

    page.bindingContext = journeyInfo;
}
```

After some research I was able to type args as

```
import app = require("application");
exports.loadSignUpView = function(args: app.ApplicationEventData) {
     //...
}
```

But that still does not help me type the page object above, which has the bindingContext property. What is the TypeScript type that corresponds to the page?

Comment: The type of the page is Page. You still need to declare the variable before you use it the function. You can declare it before the function like var page:Page.

Comment: Most - if not all - types are qualified. What's the namespace? Is it app.Page? Or is Page really a global type in the NativeScript runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page type is defined in the "ui/page" module and the type of the args of the `loaded` event is EventData (from the "data/observable" module).
So you can do something like this:

```
import observable = require("data/observable");
import pages = require("ui/page");

// Event handler for Page "loaded" event attached in main-page.xml
export function loadSignUpView (args: observable.EventData) {
    // Get the event sender
    var page = <pages.Page>args.object;
}
```

Few more useful tips to get you started:

1. NativeScript has [TypeScript support build in since the 1.5 release](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/six-major-additions-in-nativescript-1.5-release-to-skyrocket-your-developer-experience). You can now use the NativeScript CLI to setup typescript project. You can check the [documentation](http://docs.nativescript.org/transpilers) for more.
2. In the documentation there is more up to date [getting-started guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/getting-started)
3. All of the code snippets in the docs have also a TypeScript version so that you can see the typings there - we love typescript ;)